# Where to find ChromeDriver constants for browser preferences in Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, if I want to launch Chrome browser then first need to set system property like -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);
```

In this, we mentioned `wedriver.chrome.driver` but it is already defined in 'ChromeDriverService' hence can use that constant directly like ([reference doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html)) -

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, chromeDriverLocation);
```

But if I want to download a file at specific location, I give details in firefox profile like -

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", folder.getAbsolutePath());
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                "image/jpeg, application/pdf, application/octet-stream");
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    }
```

Here we can see constant values like `browser.download.dir`, `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` etc.

Are these defined as constants anywhere as we've `ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY`? So we can directly use them in the code.

Answer (score 1):

[ChromeDriverService](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html) class supports the following fields:

- [CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY)
- [CHROME_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY)
- [CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY)
- [CHROME_DRIVER_VERBOSE_LOG_PROPERTY](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_VERBOSE_LOG_PROPERTY)
- [CHROME_DRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS_PROPERTY](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS_PROPERTY)

Hence you can use:

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, chromeDriverLocation);
```

But [FirefoxProfile](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) supports three overloaded `setPreference()` methods as follows:

- [**`setPreference(java.lang.String key, boolean value)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference-java.lang.String-boolean-)
- [**`setPreference(java.lang.String key, int value)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference-java.lang.String-int-)
- [**`setPreference(java.lang.String key, java.lang.String value)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

All the three methods accepts a *key* (**String**) and a *value* (boolean/int/String) pair and sets the preference for this particular profile. Firefox Browser when starts are configured with these values.

### Conclusion

So the desired preferences e.g. `browser.download.dir`, `browser.download.folderList`, `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`, `pdfjs.disabled`, etc are not **constants** but *key* (**String**) *value* (boolean/int/String) pair and can't be treated like **constants** in your code.

Comment: `System.setProperty(key, value)` also has key and still they've declared `webdriver.chrome.driver` as constant and I did not understand why `browser.download.dir`, `browser.download.folderList`, `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`, `pdfjs.disabled` are not constants. There is nothing wrong with being them constant as they're never going to change - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, You can type `about:config` in the address bar to see all the preference name and it's current value.

For Chrome, You can type `chrome://flags` in the address bar to see all current settings and it's value.

click [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/139736/how-to-change-hidden-advanced-settings-in-any-browser/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from code:

```java
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, chromeDriverLocation);
```

or command line param

```sh
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromeDriverLocation testClass
```